# Download file using FTP on Android

Tags: android

This is my class has download files from ftp

```
public void run() {

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        String remoteFile1 = "/WhiteList.txt";
        File downloadFile1 = new File("/data/data/com.prosec/files/WhiteList.txt");

        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));

        boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
        outputStream1.close();
```

In my MainAcitivy, I instance the ftp class when I open my app (OnCreate()).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btnDicas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDicas);
    out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    new Thread(new ReceiveFTP()).start();// HERE
```

I'm problems in this line

```
OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
```

The log:

```
03-12 09:06:37.704 7457-7509/? I/System.out: Error: /data/data/com.prosec/files/WhiteList.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-12 09:06:37.704 7457-7509/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.prosec/files/WhiteList.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-12 09:06:37.704 7457-7509/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
03-12 09:06:37.712 7457-7509/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
03-12 09:06:37.712 7457-7509/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
03-12 09:06:37.712 7457-7509/? W/System.err:     at com.prosec.ReceiveFTP.run(ReceiveFTP.java:43)
```

If I closed the app, and open again, works fine. This error ocurred only first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is specifically with the `"/data/data/com.prosec/files/WhiteList.txt"` download path.

Consult [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) on saving files.

You do it either on internal storage through [`getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) or [`getCacheDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()):

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

Or on external storage using [`Environment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) class:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename);
```

Comment: getfileDir doesn't return the same dir that /data/data/myApp??

Comment: It says "The returned path may change over time if the calling app is moved to an adopted storage device, so only relative paths should be persisted" in the getFilesDir() reference